# How to Java Web Start from a local html file?

Tags: java, security, web, java-web-start

I'm trying to use Java Web Start to startup a java app from a local web page but getting security errors.  Here is the jnlp file:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
      href="dynamictree_webstart_no_codebase.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Dynamic Tree Demo No Codebase</title>
        <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="DynamicTreeDemo.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>    
    <application-desc
         name="Dynamic Tree Demo Application"
         main-class="webstartComponentArch.DynamicTreeApplication">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

If I use the following url:

```
file:///C:/Users/Greg/Desktop/JavaWebStartExamples/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/src/JavaWebStartAppPage_No_Codebase.html
```

Then I get a dialog with "Application Blocked by Java Security, Your security settings have blocked a local application from running"

So then I add "file://desktop-60nl2pl" to the Trusted Sites area in Chrome and uncheck "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone" and change the url to the following:

```
"file://desktop-60nl2pl/Users/Greg/Desktop/JavaWebStartExamples/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/src/JavaWebStartAppPage_No_Codebase.html"
```

Then a dialog pops up saying "Unable to launch the application."  Clicking the Details button reveals "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.setSourceURL(Unknown Source)
".

I've signed the jar with a self-signed crt but that apparently was not enough. 
I've read up on this problem and one possible solution seems to be that now it needs to be signed by a trusted CA cert.  Really?  Just for testing on my local computer?  Surely there is another way?

**EDIT1:  Adding in the html code by request**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Dynamic Tree Java Web Start Application - Deployed Without Codebase</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dynamic Tree Java Web Start Application Demo - Deployed Without Codebase </h1>

    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>    

    <h2>Java Web Start application deployed by using the <code>launchWebStartApplication</code> function</h2>

    <p><a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('dynamictree_webstart_no_codebase.jnlp');">Launch Dynamic Tree Demo application</a></p>

    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>

    <h2>Java Web Start application deployed by using the <code>createWebStartLaunchButtonEx</code> function</h2>    

    <script>        
        var jnlpFile = "dynamictree_webstart_no_codebase.jnlp";
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(jnlpFile);
    </script>
    <noscript>JavaScript is required for this page.</noscript>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2: Here is the web page and Blocked Error screenshots:**
[image]
[image]
I click Open Java Web Launcher and then see this Blocked error:
[image]

If I double click DynamicTreeDemo.jar, the app comes up ok.  I just won't launch from the web page.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following lines to the Exception Site List in the Java Control Panel,Security tab:

```
file:///C:/Users/Greg/Projects/Enventive/En360_UI/WebContent/DynamicTreeDemo.jar
file:///C:/Users/Greg/Projects/Enventive/En360_UI/WebContent/dynamictree_webstart_no_codebase.jnlp
```

Probably only need one of these two.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed a Java Swing application (packaged as an executable jar file) on a Apache Tomcat webserver and access the app using Java `WebStart` from a webpage; and here are some details. The JNLP file and the web page description respectively:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.thewebapp.com/"
        href="http://www.thewebapp.com/theapp-webstart.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>The Application</title>
        <vendor>A Team</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="theapp.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc
        name="The Application"
        main-class="TheApp">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The web page with the link to access the app:

```
<a href="theapp-webstart.jnlp">Click here to start the app</a>
```

The web page and the jnlp file are in the same folder (root) of the web app (its deployed as a WAR file) and on clicking the link on the webpage "Click here to start the app" the application starts on the client computer.

Also, in the Windows (7) control-panel -> Programs -> Java: this opens Java Control Panel. In the security-tab there is a check box "Enable Java content for browser and webstart applications" - check this.

Comment: That checkbox is checked on my Windows 10 Java but still getting security blocks.  Did you have to sign your jar with a Trusted Certificate Authority (CA) or were you able to get it to work with a self-signed cert?  Is there no way to test locally without having to set up Tomcat or some other web server?

Comment: I did not sign the jar with any CA or self-cert. I mostly followed what is available at this link on [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html). The deployment I had made was about 4 years back and it was a Swing app. Also, I recently deployed another web start app last month and it was JavaFX app. I didn't do anything other than what I have indicated in the post. One thing I needed to mention was the app's executable jar file was also in the same (root) folder along with the jnlp and web page.

Comment: Here is another link which specifies the [requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html) for the web start app deployment. It specifies that a web server is a requirement and it also says any web server. I deployed on a Tomcat because it was available for me. You can try with Apache Http Server, but I don't know if it will work as I have not tried it.

Comment: I installed tomcat and got the web page running on it.  Buy when I click the link to the jnlp file, I get the "blocked" error message.  I also added "http ://localhost" to the Chrome Trusted Sites area, but same result. (I added a space after http only in this post to get it to show up).

Comment: I also tried it in Firefox and Edge browsers but got the same result.  Blocked.  I'm going to try my own java program rather than the Java Web Start example app I download from Oracle.  Something funky about that program.

Comment: (1) Are using the same jnlp as in the original post? What is the <a> tag you are using the link to access the jnlp? Post all the details once again (including the app's jar file and the deployed war file). -OR- (2) Try with the settings I had posted with a small Swing/JavaFX hello-world program, and see if you are able to run a webstart application. Finally, (3) are you able to access _any_ web start application at all (most of the Oracle's Java tutorial Swing examples are web start apps, and here is one [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html))?

Comment: (1) Yes.  Although I did add the security->all permissions tag.  I have since removed it since it didn't help.  I posted the html code. (2) I will try that next. (3) Yes, I am able to access it.  I get a message "Keep or Discard"  I click Keep then it downloads it.  Then I click on the download file and I get a "Do you want to run this application?" dialog.  I click Run and the app pops up.  Also, if I double click the DynamicTreeDemo.jar file, it pops up ok.

Comment: I'm thinking Windows 10 (or Chrome for Windows 10) has more security built in than what you are using.

Comment: I also tried setting the Chrome Security Internet level to Medium (that's as low as it would go) and the Trusted Sites level to Low.  Same result.  Blocked.

Comment: I was able to get it to run by adding http ://localhost:8080/WebStartExample/ as an exception in the Java Security panel.  I shouldn't have to do that.  Examples run fine from the Oracle/Sun web pages without having to do that, why not locally?

Comment: There is quite a bit of info out there if you can do some Google search for "_java web start application blocked locally_" (I guess you are already trying that).